# How to use Arc::make_mut with a slice

Tags: rust

The following code doesn't work:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let x = (0..10).collect::<Arc<[u32]>>();
    let y = Arc::make_mut(&mut x);
}
```

I get an error that [u32] is not cloneable:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a58be8e0f73b8489fdaccc9c94f13ccb

Is there a way to make this work without using `Vec`?

Comment: `Arc::make_mut` is liek `Arc::get_mut` but it clones on failure. You can't clone a slice, so use `get_mut` instead.

Comment: i made my own `make_slice_mut`, hopefully it's safe: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e4092fb2623642067b51800b0247841